# Youtube API returning current time

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the youtube iframe api and can't seem to find anything in the documentation or on google that references how to get the returned values on current media completion.

I'm needing to build a script where I can past in time variables, in which when the variable matches up with the current time played an event can be triggered.

I know in the embed API there is one, `player.getCurrentTime():Number` but doesn't seem to be one for the iframe API. I'm sure someone would of noticed this before.

Comment: You can answer below, then select that answer is correct.  That way you can close this question out.

Comment: I'm using the youtube frame api and player.getCurrentTime() is working fine for me... even if I get a console error "player.getCurrentTime is not a function".

Comment: I couldn't do it at the time due to needing to wait 2 days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getCurrentTime` is also available in youtube iframe source.

To get current time code, I used a math.floor.

```
time = Math.floor(Video.YTPlayer.getCurrentTime());
```

This will always return whole numbers and will constantly round down numbers to its whole.