# cant get youtube video current time

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have an embedded YouTube videos in my HTML page. I'm trying to get the current time of YouTube video. I used the answer of that question to create page like this 
([YouTube currentTime with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783108/youtube-currenttime-with-jquery))

When I'm trying to display the time I'm getting an error: 'getCurrentTime is not a function'.

HTML

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play</button> 
  <button onclick="showTime()">Show Time</button>
  <br><br>
  <iframe id = "it"  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/FHtvDA0W34I?version=3&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <br>
  <label id=startHighlighlbl>VideoHighlightStart: </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script> 
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}


function ShowTime() {

    alert(player.getCurrentTime());
} 


</script>
```

Comment: try changing `player` in `new YT.Player('player'` to new `YT.Player('it'` ... or change `id="it"` to `id="player"` in your HTML

Comment: here is a pen modified to work http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvXmEp?editors=101

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should load your video through the YT-API, so `player` is initialized correctly and thus accessible through the API. Basically you need to remove your `iframe` from your HTML and instead let YT-API create the iframe for you.

Try the following:

```js
   var tag = document.createElement('script');

   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

   var player;

   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
     player = new YT.Player('it', {
       height: '315',
       width: '560',
       videoId: 'FHtvDA0W34I',
       events: {
         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
       }
     });
   }

   function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.playVideo();
   }

   var done = false;

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
     if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
       setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
       done = true;
     }
   }

   function stopVideo() {
     player.stopVideo();
   }

   function ShowTime() {
     alert(player.getCurrentTime());
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="ShowTime()">Show Time</button>
  <br>
  <div id="it"></div>
</body
```

Comment: `Basically you need to remove your iframe from your HTML` that wasn't the issue. The **only** issue was the `id="it"` in the `<iframe>` vs `"player"` in the JS code - no reason not to use the code in the question otherwise

Comment: You are correct. I saw that the wrong id a bit late.